# How to combine two vector layers into one combined layer?

Tags: qgis, combine, normalize

I made two layers for heat stress (PET) and flooding risk. I normalized both maps into a 0-100 scale. The number 0 means a low heat stress/flooding risk and 100 is a high heat stress/flooding risk.

To show which areas are in most need of green infrastructure, I need a combined map of these two layers. Does someone have an idea how I can combine these layers (still normalized?)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry the values here are not right. The values differ per neighbourhood..

Comment: Are you asking how to `join attributes by location`?

Comment: or do you want a bivariate map? https://www.artlembo.com/post/easy-bivariate-maps-with-qgis-sql-and-the-db-manager

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be two tasks here: first combine the attributes from two layers into a single layer, and then do whatever needs doing to the heat and flood attributes to compute a new standardised value.

For the first part, assuming the polygon geometries originally come from *exactly* the same file, use "Join attributes by location" on "equal" polygons. My test data has a "heat" layer and a "flood" layer:

[image]

The resulting "Joined layer" has attributes from both:

[image]

Then you can compute your combined index, naively maybe by using `("FLOOD" + "HEIGHT") / 2`, or with a more complex expression if you want to normalise between 0 and 100.